# Nginx Owncloud security measures?

Tags: nginx

OwnCloud is giving me:

- The `X-XSS-Protection` HTTP header is not configured to equal to `"1; mode=block"`
  . This is a potential security or privacy risk and we
  recommend adjusting this setting.
- The `X-Content-Type-Options` HTTP header is not configured to equal
  to `nosniff`. 
  This is a potential security or privacy risk and we
  recommend adjusting this setting.
- The `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header is not configured to equal to
  `SAMEORIGIN`. 
  This is a potential security or privacy risk and we
  recommend adjusting this setting.

How should I secure it?

Answer (score 1):

Security tests are only for guidance. Let's first see what these options are to understand what exactly they do and how necessary they are.

- The [`HTTP X-XSS-Protection` XSS Filter](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/01/31/controlling-the-xss-filter/) is activated (`1`) by default, so you either have disabled it by setting `0` or OwnCloud suggest you to set `X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block`, which will cause more than sanitizing: the browser won't render the page at all, but show only `#` instead.

  > The [`HTTP X-XSS-Protection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection) response header is a feature of Internet
  >   Explorer, Chrome and Safari that stops pages from loading when they
  >   detect reflected cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. Although these
  >   protections are largely unnecessary in modern browsers when sites
  >   implement a strong [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) that disables the use of
  >   inline JavaScript (`'unsafe-inline'`), they can still provide
  >   protections for users of older web browsers that don't yet support
  >   CSP.

  Although suggested by the test, you'll probably be just fine with the default setting.
- [IE8 `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2008/09/02/ie8-security-part-vi-beta-2-update/) blocks a request if the MIME type doesn't match the the requested type in `style` / `script`. Supported currently by all major browsers except Safari.

  > The [`X-Content-Type-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options) response HTTP header is a marker used by
  >   the server to indicate that the [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) advertised in the
  >   [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) headers should not be changed and be followed. This
  >   allows to opt-out of [MIME type sniffing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#MIME_sniffing), or, in other words, it is a
  >   way to say that the webmasters knew what they were doing.
- [`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) allows browser to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>` only if it is from the same origin as the page itself.

  This is a good measurement against XSS, but it means that you cannot embed *any* external content with these tags, even when the source is legitimate, e.g. a YouTube video. In this case settings `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://www.youtube.com/` would keep you safe from other sources, but you'd still get an error from this test.

When you understand the purpose of these headers, you can set them correctly to increase security without losing any functionality necessary for your site. All XSS prevention methods are good especially for sites where users or employees create content. On a static site where you know what you are doing and have control over every page they may sometimes be unnecessarily restrictive.

With this information, it's not difficult at all to set these headers in Nginx with [`add_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header):

```
   add_header  X-XSS-Protection        "1; mode=block";
   add_header  X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff;
   add_header  X-Frame-Options         SAMEORIGIN;
```

These can be set globally in `http` context or specific to `server`, `location`, or `if` in `location`.